# Obtener la clave del objeto json principal usando axios

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios

Tengo un problema y es que estoy consultando el *API REST* de **Firebase** con `axios` y `vue js`.
Cuando consulto al archivo `.json` de la *API* me devuelve este objeto, sólo tengo un documento guardado:

```
{"-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O":{"code_cr":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","coupon_id":"-Lf6LcbEF6dEkgwW0MSm","id":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","redeem_date":"2019-08-10 15:30","user_id":"-LnNxAURsniPfQE54UM0"}}
```

Entonces lo que quiero es obtener la clave**(el id del documento)** del objeto `json` que es: "-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O".
En mi componente de `Vue` almaceno los datos consultados en variable **(array)** de la data del componente, entonces sólo recorro ese **array** para mostrar los datos en una tabla así:

```
 <tr v-for="(cp,index) in couponsRedeem" v-bind:key="index">
            <td>{{cp.user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{cp.coupon_id}}</td>
            <td>{{cp.redeem_date}}</td>

             <td>{{cp.id}}</td>
             <td>{{cp.id}}</td>
             <td> <b-btn  variant="primary" size="sm" :to="{name: 'detail- 
             coupon', params:{}}">SEE MORE</b-btn></td>

        </tr>
```

Como ven puedo acceder a las claves del objeto que está dentro del objeto principal, pero lo que quiero es obtener la clave del objeto principal **("-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O")** para mandarlo como parametro a otra ruta para renderizar otro componente y hacer petición.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer la primera propiedad de ese objeto mediante el metodo keys de Object. Ejemplo:

```js
var jsonText = '{"-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O":{"code_cr":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","coupon_id":"-Lf6LcbEF6dEkgwW0MSm","id":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","redeem_date":"2019-08-10 15:30","user_id":"-LnNxAURsniPfQE54UM0"}}';
var tuObjeto = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var id = Object.keys(tuObjeto)[0];
console.log(id);
```